# EXTRACT Value from a mixed string

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-access

I am trying  to extract a numeric value assigned from a  cell in a column of such values.

```
CELL A1- CONSUMER id-23014875,Alias-35,ISE-4
CELL A2- Alias-65,ISE-9, CONSUMER id-27714875
```

End result required has to be Consumer Id and its values

Comment: =MID(A1,SEARCH("CONSUMER id",A1),20)    will return CONSUMER id- followed by 9 letter number that follows. This assumes that the number is always 9 letters in length. This won't work if you wish to return numbers following Alias & ISE though. Please clarify further.

Answer (score 1):

In **B1** enter:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("CONSUMER id-",A1)+12,9999) & ","
```

and in **C1** enter:

```
=LEFT(B1,FIND(",",B1)-1)
```

and copy these cells downwards:

[image]

If desired, these can be combined into a single formula.

```
=LEFT((MID(A1,FIND("CONSUMER id-",A1)+12,9999) & ","),FIND(",",(MID(A1,FIND("CONSUMER id-",A1)+12,9999) & ","))-1)
```